# Inequality with convex functions

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

> A function $f : I\to \mathbb{R}$ is convex on an interval $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ when $\lambda f(x) + (1 − \lambda)f (y) \ge f (\lambda x+(1 − \lambda)y )$ holds for all $x,y \in I$. Prove
> $$
> \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i f(x_i) \ge  f\left(\sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i x_i\right)
> $$
> holds for all $n\ge 2, x_1, \ldots, x_n \in I$ and $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n \ge 0$ satisfying $1 =  \sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i$.

**My Attempt:**

If $\lambda_1>0$ then I take $\lambda_0 = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2$
and $\Lambda_1 = \lambda_1/\lambda_0, \Lambda_2 = \lambda_2/\lambda_0, x_0 = \Lambda_1 x_1 + \Lambda_2 x_2$
and
$$
\lambda_0(\Lambda_1 f(x_1) + \Lambda_2 f(x_2)) + \sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_i f(x_i).
$$
Pls help me on what to do next and how to complete the proof

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**
I would proceed by Induction. The base case $n=2$ is already given, so let's inductively assume this holds for all $n$ up to $k-1$, and then prove it for $n=k$.

Assume WLOG that $\lambda_0 \ne 0$ (otherwise, you must have some non-zero coefficient since they have to sum up to 1, so pick any non-zero coefficient and renumber them).

Let $x = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} x_i \lambda_i/1-\lambda_k$. Then by the inductive assumption, we have
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} f(x_i) \frac{\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_k} 
 \ge f\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} x_i \frac{\lambda_i}{1-\lambda_k} \right)
 = f(x)
$$
and since $I$ is convex, $x \in I$. Then,
$$
f\left(\sum_{i=0}^k x_i \lambda_i \right)
 = f\left((1-\lambda_k) x + \lambda_k x_k \right)
 \le (1-\lambda_k) f(x) + \lambda_k f(x_k)
$$

Can you finish?

Comment: $\lambda_0$ in the proof should be replaced by $1-\lambda_k$.

Comment: @Khue +1, thank you, changed.